# DOMpdf - Page break removes <td> that has rowspan

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table, dompdf

I have this html table that is rendered using `DomPDF` in my `Codeigniter(PHP)` app.
The `header` `Terminal` in the table serve as the group name. Therefor if it has more than 1 data.
Its `rowspan` wil expand across rows.
This works well in the first page of the `pdf` But when it `page breaks` the `<td>` for `Terminal` value is removed completely. Data are moved to left part of the pages.

Can anyone help me here? I've been looking for the solution but no good.

First page
[image]

Second page
[image]

When new terminal, this what happens
[image]

```
<table class="content">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Terminal</th>
        <th rowspan="2">ETA Date</th>
        <th rowspan="2">ETA Time</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Vessel Name</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Available Date</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Storage Start Date</th>
        <th colspan="2">20</th>
        <th colspan="2">40</th>
        <th rowspan="2">TEU</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>TEU</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>TEU</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="page-break-inside: avoid;">

<?php
    // Iterate through the grouped data
    foreach ($group_containers as $wharf => $rows) {
        // Calculate the number of rows in this group
        $rowCount = count($rows);

        foreach ($rows as $index => $row) { ?>
           <tr>
    
        <?php if ($index === 0) { ?>
             <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowCount; ?>" style="border-top: 1px dotted #000; border-right: 1px dotted #000; padding: 5px; font-weight: 400; color: #333333;vertical-align: baseline;text-align: center;font-size: 14px;"><?php echo $wharf; ?></td>
        <?php  } ?>
                <td><?php echo $row->eta_date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->eta_time; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->vessel_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->available_date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->storage_start_date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->{'20_count'}; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->{'20_teu'}; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->{'40_count'}; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->{'40_teu'}; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->total_teu; ?></td>

            </tr>
       <?php } ?>
<?php }  ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but can not find any solution.